# Suggestion:Need a carousel slider in wordpress[images from api]

Tags: wordpress

Consider a table containing image URLs and some count for each image
so my API is returning top 5(limit can be changed) image links according to count in descending order

Here is sample images table:
[image]

this is API response(the image will become suffix `www.hostname.com/IMAGE_ID`)
[image]

Now I want to show these images as a carousel in WordPress.

SO ANY SUGGESTION FOR PLUGINS AVAILABLE IN WORDPRESS?

Comment: What have you tried so far in WordPress to display?

Comment: I've tried to do something custom html  http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/demos/customJson.html